# Linux Ubuntu ALSA issues; after reboot sound is turned off

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, speakers, alsa

I'm using Ubuntu with Xfce, ALSA, `pavucontrol`, …

After I reboot the system my sound always goes off.

And my speakers in `alsamixer` are listed as Headphones (which I have to always increase the volume after boot so it works).

What can I be doing wrong that the sound isn't saved?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

$ uname -r
4.16.12

$ alsactl -version
alsactl version 1.1.3
```

`alsamixer` controls the sound OK, Master and Speaker are the same but Headphones also controls the volume.

```
$ pavucontrol 
Package: pavucontrol
Version: 3.0-4
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82561/discussion-between-chai-t-rex-and-fernando-andre).

Comment: In output devices I only have those two, in configuration I have many options.
several are related to hdmi , one is duplex stereo analog witch is selected. another is output analog stereo
More info on pulse audio and alsa here https://askubuntu.com/questions/426983/how-can-i-tell-if-im-using-alsa-or-pulse-audio-by-default-switching-to-i3-wm

Comment: We used the link found by Chris https://askubuntu.com/questions/50067/howto-save-alsamixer-settings/606115#606115 , the third answer with a sleep option as sugested in the comments for the autostart alsaactl --file xxx restore

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the pavucontrol does not work well with alsa.

To solve this issue the only way it seems to work is to follow 
the third answer at 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/50067/howto-save-alsamixer-settings/606115#606115

some modifications are required following the comments
like adding a sleep to the Exec
So to have the settings save after reboot
you need to create a configuration stored file
alsactl --file ~/.config/autostart/asound.state store

and then restore that configuration in a autostart boot script

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=alsarestore
Exec=bash -c "sleep 5 && alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state restore"
```

in ~/.config/autostart/alsarestore.desktop

Comment: Please note there is no fixed order of answers, any user can choose from three options. The answer you link to is third according to votes *now*, these votes can change in the future. So the term "third answer" is ill-defined and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

The setup where this solution worked:

- Ubuntu 18.04 (GNOME), not xfce
- gnome alsa mixer, not pavucontrol
- realtek alc1220 on the X470 AORUS GAMING 7 WIFI rev1.0

However, the core problem was the same:

1. Speakers from the back panel were detected as a headphones line.
2. After a reboot or relog, the line was muted and had zero level in the gnome alsa mixer.

### Solution

Almost 9 years old [answer on ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1430224&p=8969595#post8969595) helped. Citing it:

> I managed to get it to work as expected by replacing the line
>
> `load-module module-device-restore`
>
> in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` with
>
> `#load-module module-device-restore`

### Partial solution (just to beware)

Before finding out the solution I tried [another approach](https://askubuntu.com/a/147603).
I changed the respective block of `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-lineout.conf` to

```
[Element Speaker]
switch = on
volume = ignore
```

Unfortunately, it only unchecks the "mute" checkbox, leaving the line level on the zero mark. So, don't use it.